# C# Tasks - am I experiencing a suspicious increasing of number of handles

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I am dipping my toes in Tasks (.NET 4.5) and am experiencing increasing handles (in task manager). I have a class doing a simple Play/Stop of audio file using MediaPlayer class (System.Windows.Media namespace). I have a second class which wraps it and exposes sync/async playback.
All is working fine and functionality is OK, but see the number of handles increasing in Task manager which worries me.... Am I doing something wrong here?

**Important note: if I comment our the "await Task.Delay(1000);" --> then all is just fine and no leaks are observed... How come??**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    AudioActions syncAction = new AudioActions(@"c:\1.wav", false);
    AudioActions asyncAction = new AudioActions(@"c:\1.wav", true);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void syncPlayback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await syncAction.Start();
        }
    }

    private async void asyncPlayback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            await asyncAction.Start();
            await Task.Delay(100); //remove this line and all is fine!!!!
            asyncAction.Stop();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("done");
    }
}

public class AudioActions
{
    private Audio audio = null;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;
    private string pathToWaveFile;
    private bool async;

    public AudioActions(string pathToWaveFile, bool async)
    {
        this.pathToWaveFile=pathToWaveFile;
        this.async=async;
    }

    public Task Start()
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        audio = new Audio();
        audio.mediaPlayerPlaybackStoppedEvent += Audio_wmPlaybackStopped;

        if (async)
            tcs.TrySetResult(true); //since its async operation, lets return immediately and free the task from waiting

        audio.PlayAudioFileInMediaPlayer(pathToWaveFile);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private void Audio_wmPlaybackStopped()
    {
        audio.mediaPlayerPlaybackStoppedEvent -= Audio_wmPlaybackStopped;
        tcs.TrySetResult(true); //playback stopped. Lets free the task from waiting
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        audio.StopAudioFilePlaybackInMediaPlayer();
    }
}

public class Audio
{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    public delegate void MediaPlayerPlaybackStoppedDelegate();
    public event MediaPlayerPlaybackStoppedDelegate mediaPlayerPlaybackStoppedEvent;

    public void PlayAudioFileInMediaPlayer(string pathToWavFile)
    {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += mediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
        mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(pathToWavFile));
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    }

    void mediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mediaPlayerPlaybackStoppedEvent.Invoke();
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = (MediaPlayer)sender;
        mediaPlayer.MediaEnded -= mediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
        mediaPlayer.Close();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }

    public void StopAudioFilePlaybackInMediaPlayer()
    {
        mediaPlayer.Stop();
        mediaPlayer.Close();
        mediaPlayer = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Adding a strip down code:

```
private async void asyncPlayback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AudioActions asyncAction = new AudioActions();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        await asyncAction.Start();
        await Task.Delay(1000); //remove this line and all is fine!!!!
        asyncAction.Stop();
    }
}

public class AudioActions
{
    private Audio audio = null;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;

    public Task Start()
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        audio = new Audio();
        tcs.TrySetResult(true); //since its async operation, lets return immediately and free the task from waiting

        audio.PlayAudioFileInMediaPlayer(@"c:\1.wav");
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        audio.StopAudioFilePlaybackInMediaPlayer();
    }
}

public class Audio
{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    public void PlayAudioFileInMediaPlayer(string pathToWavFile)
    {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(pathToWavFile));
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    }

    public void StopAudioFilePlaybackInMediaPlayer()
    {
        mediaPlayer.Stop();
        mediaPlayer.Close();
        mediaPlayer = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Modified class solving the problem:

```
public class Audio
{
    public delegate void NaudioPlaybackStoppedDelegate();
    public event NaudioPlaybackStoppedDelegate naudioPlaybackStoppedEvent;

    private WaveOut player = null;

    public void PlayAudioFileUsingNaudio(string pathToWavFile)
    {
        player = new WaveOut();
        AudioFileReader waveFileReader = new AudioFileReader(pathToWavFile);
        player.Init(waveFileReader);
        player.PlaybackStopped += NAudio_Stopped;
        player.Play();
    }

    private void NAudio_Stopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        player.PlaybackStopped -= NAudio_Stopped;
        if (naudioPlaybackStoppedEvent!=null)
            naudioPlaybackStoppedEvent.Invoke();
        player.Dispose();
    }

    public void StopAudioFilePlaybackInNaudio()
    {
        player.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of things I wouldn't be doing, however, these wouldn't appear to be the cause of the memory leak. First step - run it using the sync action only and determine whether the memory leak still exists, my suspicion is it's related to the `MediaPlayer` stuff not being cleaned up.

Comment: What does this have to do with deadlocks? Does your code end up in a deadlock or not?

Comment: Minor note - You should never call `GC.Collect` outside of diagnostic code.

Comment: The number of handles are due to the allocation of `MediaPlayer`. I just tested this out myself, both allocating and calling `mediaPlayer.Close()` cause additional handles to be allocated. You're seeing an increase in those handles since the GC is non-deterministic and hasn't run yet.

Comment: @James - using the sync action, it doesn't seem to be leaking

Comment: @LorenB and if you run the same test but this time using the `async` method, does it leak?

Comment: @Yuval - Thanks for testing my code. You said that the GC hasn't run yet, but please note that I'm explicitly calling it in the "StopAudioFilePlaybackInMediaPlayer" method. If I remove the GC.Collect(), you will see thousands of handles quite immediately.

Comment: @James - Yes, James, the async method is leaking...

Comment: 1 important note I forgot to mention which is crucial - on the async method (on the event handler), if I comment out the "await Task.Delay(100);" - no leaks at all are observed!!

Comment: How is `asyncPlayback` being called?

Comment: @JohnOdom - Hi John, its being called by using a button on a WinForm application. This is the event handler of the button press event.

Comment: Could you possibly recreate the issue in a small test application with minimal code? Also have you tried debugging to see if the `Task.Delay` function is returning? It could be that the handles are not getting closed because `Task.Delay` is not returning, so the `Stop` function is not being called.

Comment: @JohnOdom - Thanks, John, I am posting above a strip-down and minimal code. To answer your question, yes, the Task.Delay is returning.

Comment: Somehow I seriously doubt it's `Task` that's causing memory to be leaked...

Comment: @aevitas It's most likely not but just to be sure LorenB should add logs to it or debug through it to make sure that `asyncAction.Stop();` is being called.

Comment: I have find a solution for this issue. Looks like the issue is related to media player. I have confirmed it by using a 3rd party audio library (NAudio) and all is working fine now. To prove it, I have left the code as is and replaced only the low level calls to playback. See above the modified class. Thank you all for participating and for your time spent.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing MediaPlayer with NAudio 3rd party solved it.

```
public class Audio
{
    public delegate void NaudioPlaybackStoppedDelegate();
    public event NaudioPlaybackStoppedDelegate naudioPlaybackStoppedEvent;

    private WaveOut player = null;

    public void PlayAudioFileUsingNaudio(string pathToWavFile)
    {
        player = new WaveOut();
        AudioFileReader waveFileReader = new AudioFileReader(pathToWavFile);
        player.Init(waveFileReader);
        player.PlaybackStopped += NAudio_Stopped;
        player.Play();
    }

    private void NAudio_Stopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        player.PlaybackStopped -= NAudio_Stopped;
        if (naudioPlaybackStoppedEvent!=null)
            naudioPlaybackStoppedEvent.Invoke();
        player.Dispose();
    }

    public void StopAudioFilePlaybackInNaudio()
    {
        player.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or in other words: "I threw away everything I had and learned nothing about the problem".  This is not helpful to anybody else of course.

Comment: @HansPassant - not at all, I have been dealing with this problem for few weeks now and still investigating though it consumes a lot of time. Since I suspect (only suspect) a leak in MediaPlayer, I marked it as a temporary answer as no one else mentioned any problem in the above code for the past 2 days. The fact its working with a 3rd party lib doesn't make me happy but it give a certain clue that the code is OK, unless I'm missing something else.